# Await for an element not to appear

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I need to write a test that once a permissions API promise is resolved makes sure an element will not be visible.

I've written a test based on [the docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/#waiting-for-disappearance) however, it seems to only work when an element is initially present. My problem is that the element ('Test' string) is not present and will remain not present as long as userPermissions does not include a requiredPermission so the test will pass regardless of whether I pass the right permissions or not. Even when 'Test' actually appears on the page the test `expect(queryByText('Test')).not.toBeInTheDocument()` passes...

I would like to be sure that an element will not appear after my await.

```
it('returns null if user does not have a permission', async () => {
  fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify({ read: false }));
  render(
    <PermissionsProvider>
      <HasPermission requiredPermission="read">Test</HasPermission>
    </PermissionsProvider>
  );

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(queryByText('Test')).not.toBeInTheDocument()
  });
});
```

This is the `HasPermission` component

```
export const HasPermission = ({ children, requiredPermission }) => {
  const { permissions: userPermissions } = useContext(PermissionsContext);

  const match = userPermissions.some(permission => requiredPermission);

  if (match) {
    return <>{children}</>;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

and my `PermissionsProvider`

```
const PermissionsContext = createContext(null);

export const PermissionsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPermissions = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('/permissions');
      setPermissions(response);
    };
    fetchPermissions();
  }, []);

  return (
    <PermissionsContext.Provider value={{ permissions }}>{children}</PermissionsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: You sure the data being fetched it returning the correct info?

Answer (score 0):

The code to render and update React components need to be included in React’s call stack. React testing library already integrated [act](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#act) with its APIs. So in most cases, we do not need to wrap render and fireEvent in act. But you can try it:

```
act(()=> {
  render(
     <PermissionsProvider>
       <HasPermission requiredPermission="read">Test</HasPermission>
     </PermissionsProvider>
  );
});
```

But reading your code, I think your problem is here:

```
const match = userPermissions.some(permission => requiredPermission);
```

Because userPermissions is an `typeof Object` not `Array`. Are you trying to match the component's permission with some property in userPermissions?

```
 const match = userPermissions[requiredPermission];
```

Comment: I thought `waitFor` used `act` under the hood anyway?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes You will need to use it, let me know how it goes

Comment: @ReturnOfTheMac I think this is always true-> const match = userPermissions.some(permission => requiredPermission); because requiredPermission is not an empty string and you are treating userPermissions as an Array, but it is an object, I think your problem is here, are you trying to something like this-> const match = Object.entries(userPermissions).some(([key, value])=> key === requiredPermission && value) ????

Comment: Yea I think the logic that displays the component is wrong, so the test is passing correctly.

Comment: try this  const match = userPermissions[requiredPermission];

Comment: It still does not work as expected even with the match you've provided. The `waitFor` and the expect seem to be the issue here. You may try this with an empty userPermissions object or a correct one. Both objects make the test pass. `screen.debug()` and shows the 'Test' string is there but the test passes.

Comment: try without the waitFor, just expect(queryByText('Test')).not.toBeInTheDocument()